# Temporily disable plank (with a keyboard shortcut)

Tags: release-freya, plank

Sometimes when I am learning to use Blender or programming when my mouse goes to the bottom plank pops up.

This is very annoying so I would like a keyboard shortcut to disable it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure it's possible to disable plank, but if you install Elementary Tweaks you can move plank to the left or right side of the screen.

Hope this helps.

Actually in 0.4 loki you don't even need Elemenetary Tweaks: you can ctrl + click on Plank and set its position in  the *Preferences* dialog.

Comment: With a keyboard shortcut?

Comment: I don't think there's a keyboard shortcut. Not unless you make one. But the solution might be to move plank to the left side of the screen. It was constantly popping up when I had it at the bottom. Now it's at the left I very rarely  found find plank far less likely to pop up when it's on the left side of the screen.

Comment: What I meant to say was: I don't think there's a keyboard shortcut. Probably not unless you make one. If that's not possible then you might want to consider moving plank to the left of the screen. I've found it rarely pops up in that position. When plank was at the bottom of my screen it was constantly popping up and getting in my way. Sorry if that was confused but I left the screen to answer the door and stackexchange wouldn't let me continuing editing the comment so it made some kind of sense.

Comment: Is there a dconf setting or something.I could make my keyboard shortcut run that command